# New Firebase >=9.0.0 JVM client version with Password Authentication (Desktop)

Tags: java, javafx, firebase, jvm, firebase-authentication

I have an app that is written in JavaFX that uses the old firebase-jvm library. It uses password authentication and each app is treated as a separate user.

The new library is labelled firebase-server and has NO client authentication APIs, forcing a client based implementation to fallback to a service account.

Anybody having the same issue or have workarounds?

Can the android version be used for JVM? If so, where can I get the direct link?